# Rails, warnings on Validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

hi all what i am trying to do is create a "soft" validation in other words instead of my failing the validation and not saving the data to the DB, id like to have the validation give a warning to the user and allow the user to save faulty data if they so choose. but the validator will give them a warning before.

i want to do somehting like the following:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  warnings do
    validate :warnings_validation
  end

  def warnings_validation
    warnings.add(:name_of_element, "warning message") unless x == x
  end
end
```

my model uses alot of inheritance and so gems like [validations_scope](https://github.com/gtd/validation_scopes) dont work any ideas what i can do/use ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to report record validation warnings as well as errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628628/efficient-way-to-report-record-validation-warnings-as-well-as-errors)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could inspire yourself from the ActiveModel::Error [example](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html) to implement the warning feature.

**Explanation** :

If you look at how the data is validated in Active Record, simply take a look at the `valid?` method :

```
  def valid?(context = nil)
    context ||= default_validation_context
    output = super(context)
    errors.empty? && output
  end
```

The context and the output is not important, what matter is that the `valid?` method check if the `errors` instance variable is empty or not.

In other words, in the previous link I gave you, simply renaming the `errors` instance variable into `warnings` should do the trick. You'd have to create a custom validator using rails built-in and then simply call `warnings.add(:name, "error")` when needed. It should save the records while populating the `warnings` variable.

Answer (score -1):

see this - [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations)

try this

```
  validate :warnings_validation
  def warnings_validation
    self.name_of_element.blank?
      errors.add(:name_of_element, "warning message") unless x == x
    end
  end
```

Comment: in that case the validation will stop data to be written to the DB. if x != X then the error will be given and the element wont be saved. i want to use the validator as a sort of filter to see if elements are 'suspicious' eg. there is a list of items adding up to 13, the user can then in the total column change 13 to 15 and save. the validator will kick in once he tries to save and the warning will be given "total doesnt add up", but it will still save 15 to the DB.. i dont know if that example helps clear it up